# Jeffrey's prior for variance

Tags: bayesian, variance, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm dealing with hierarchical model where $Y_i$ are from normal distribution.
About variance the formulation is the following:
Similarly, the data contain substantial information about the measurement error, $\sigma^2$, so the relatively noninformative Jeffreys' prior, $l/\sigma^2$, was used for this parameter
So, what exactly prior should I chose?
Could you give some practical reasons so that I won't need to read lots of literature about Jeffrey's prior?

Answer (score 7):

Those two are my favorite questions about the subject:

[Weakly informative prior distributions for scale parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/weakly-informative-prior-distributions-for-scale-parameters)

[What is an "uninformative prior"? Can we ever have one with truly no information?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information)

Also, it might help taking a look at section 2.9 of:

> Gelman, Carlin, Stern and Rubin (2004), [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158488388X).

And also Gelman's paper mentioned in @Michael Chernick answer:

> A. Gelman (2006), [Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models](http://ba.stat.cmu.edu/journal/2006/vol01/issue03/gelman.pdf), *Bayesian Analysis*, vol. 1, no. 3, pp. 515–533.