# What would a robust Bayesian model for estimating the scale of a roughly normal distribution be?

Tags: r, bayesian, estimation, standard-deviation, robust

There exists a number of [robust estimators of scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale). A notable example is the median absolute deviation which relates to the standard deviation as $\sigma = \mathrm{MAD}\cdot1.4826$. In a Bayesian framework there exist a number of ways to robustly estimate the *location* of a roughly normal distribution (say a Normal contaminated by outliers), for example, one could assume the data is distributed as a t distribution or Laplace distribution. Now my question:

**What would a Bayesian model for measuring the *scale* of a roughly normal distribution in a robust way be, robust in the same sense as the MAD or similar robust estimators?**

As is the case with MAD, it would be neat if the Bayesian model could approach the SD of a normal distribution in the case when the distribution of the data actually is normally distributed.

*edit 1:*

A typical example of a model that is robust against contamination/outliers when assuming the data $y_i$ is *roughly* normal is using a t distribution like:

$$y_i \sim \mathrm{t}(m, s,\nu)$$

Where $m$ is the mean, $s$ is the scale, and $\nu$ is the degree-of-freedom. With suitable priors on $m, s$ and $\nu$, $m$ will be an estimate of the mean of $y_i$ that will be robust against outliers. However, $s$ will not be a consistent estimate of the SD of $y_i$ as $s$ depends on $\nu$. For example, if $\nu$ would be fixed to 4.0 and the model above would be fitted to a huge number of samples from a $\mathrm{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$ distribution then $s$ would be around 0.82. What I'm looking for is a model which is robust, like the t model, but for the SD instead of (or in addition to) the mean.

*edit 2:*

Here follows a coded example in R and JAGS of how the t-model mentioned above is more robust with respect to the mean.

```
# generating some contaminated data
y <- c( rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=10), 
        rnorm(10, mean=100, sd= 100))

#### A "standard" normal model ####
model_string <- "model{
  for(i in 1:length(y)) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu, inv_sigma2)
  }

  mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)
  inv_sigma2 ~ dgamma(0.0001, 0.0001)
  sigma <- 1 / sqrt(inv_sigma2)
}"

model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), list(y = y))
mcmc_samples <- coda.samples(model, "mu", n.iter=10000)
summary(mcmc_samples)

### The quantiles of the posterior of mu
##  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% 
##   9.8  14.3  16.8  19.2  24.1 

#### A (more) robust t-model ####
library(rjags)
model_string <- "model{
  for(i in 1:length(y)) {
    y[i] ~ dt(mu, inv_s2, nu)
  }

  mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)
  inv_s2 ~ dgamma(0.0001,0.0001)
  s <- 1 / sqrt(inv_s2)
  nu ~ dexp(1/30) 
}"

model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), list(y = y))
mcmc_samples <- coda.samples(model, "mu", n.iter=1000)
summary(mcmc_samples)

### The quantiles of the posterior of mu
## 2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% 
##8.03  9.35  9.99 10.71 12.14
```

Comment: Maybe it's not robust enough, but the chi-squared distribution is the usually chosen conjugate prior for the inverse of the variance.

Comment: You might want to see if the first answer to this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/weakly-informative-prior-distributions-for-scale-parameters is sufficient for you; it may well not be, but maybe it is.

Comment: What is you prior for the level of the contamination? Will the contamination be systematic? Random? Will it be generated by a single distribution, or multiple distributions? Do we know something about the noise distribution(s)? If at least some of the things above are known, then we could fit some sort of a mixture model. Otherwise, I am not sure what your beliefs about this problem actually are, and if you don't have any than this seems like a very vague setting. You need to fix something, otherwise you can randomly pick a point and declare it to be the only Gaussian generated point with.

Comment: But in general, you could either fit a t-distribution which is more resistant against outliers, or a mixture of t-distributions. I'm sure there are many papers, here is one by Bishop http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/downloads/Bishop-robust-mixture-Neurocomputing-04.pdf and here is an R-package to fit mixtures: http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/~gjm/mix_soft/EMMIX_R/EMMIX-manual.pdf

Comment: @jbowman I'm not only looking for a robust prior, I'm looking for the whole kit, both a distribution for the data and a prior.

Comment: @means-to-meaning I don't have a specific dataset in mind for this question, this is more of a general question, but for the sake of argument something akin to t-distributed data is what I'm thinking of. A problem with using a t-distribution to retrieve the scale is that the scale parameter of the t does not approach the SD of (truly) normally distributed data if the DF of the t is low. The distribution used to model data does not have to look like the data however, the laplace distribution can be used to robustly estimate the location even if the data is far from laplace distributed.

Comment: Your $\sigma = \mathrm{MAD}\cdot1.4826$ is true for a normally distributed population, but not for most other distributions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bayesian inference in a T noise model with an appropriate prior will give a robust estimate of location and scale.  The precise conditions that the likelihood and prior need to satisfy are given in the paper [Bayesian robustness modelling of location and scale parameters](http://www.tonyohagan.co.uk/academic/pdf/loc-sca.pdf) by Andrade and O'Hagan (2011). 
The estimates are robust in the sense that a single observation cannot make the estimates arbitrarily large, as demonstrated in figure 2 of the paper.

When the data is normally distributed, the SD of the fitted T distribution (for fixed $\nu$) does not match the SD of the generating distribution.  But this is easy to fix.
Let $\sigma$ be the standard deviation of the generating distribution and let $s$ be the standard deviation of the fitted T distribution.
If the data is scaled by 2, then from the form of the likelihood we know that $s$ must scale by 2.
This implies that $s = \sigma f(\nu)$ for some fixed function $f$.
This function can be computed numerically by simulation from a standard normal. Here is the code to do this:

```
library(stats)
library(stats4)
y = rnorm(100000, mean=0,sd=1)
nu = 4
nLL = function(s) -sum(stats::dt(y/s,nu,log=TRUE)-log(s))
fit = mle(nLL, start=list(s=1), method="Brent", lower=0.5, upper=2)
# the variance of a standard T is nu/(nu-2)
print(coef(fit)*sqrt(nu/(nu-2)))
```

For example, at $\nu=4$ I get $f(\nu)=1.18$.
The desired estimator is then $\hat{\sigma} = s/f(\nu)$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). 'in the sense that a single observation cannot make the estimates arbitrarily large,' so the breakdown point is 2/n (I was wondering about this)....As a point of comparison, for the procedure illustrated in my answer it is n/2.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Fuzzy follow up question. Would it then actually *make sense* to "correct" the scale so it's consistent with the SD in the Normal case? The use case I'm thinking of is when reporting a measure of spread. I would have no problem with reporting scale, but it would be nice to report something that would be consistent with SD as it is the most common measure of spread (at least in psychology). Do you see a situation where this correction would lead to strange and inconsistent estimates?

Answer (score 6):

As you are asking a question about a  very precise problem (robust estimation), I will offer you an equally precise answer. First, however, I will begin be trying to dispel an unwarranted assumption. It is not true that there is a robust bayesian 
estimate of location (there are bayesian estimators of locations but as I illustrate below they are not robust and, [apparently](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82128/what-would-a-robust-bayesian-model-for-estimating-the-scale-of-a-roughly-normal/86447#comment168775_86447), even the simplest robust estimator of location is not bayesian) . In my opinion, the reasons for the absence of overlap between the 'bayesian' and 'robust' paradigm in the location case goes a long way in explaining why there also are no estimators of scatter that are both robust and bayesian .

> With suitable priors on $m, s$ and $\nu$, $m$ will be an estimate of
>   the mean of $y_i$ that will be robust against outliers.

Actually, no. The resulting estimates will only be robust in a *very* weak sense of the word robust. However, when we say that the median is *robust* to outliers we mean the word *robust* in a much stronger sense. That is, in robust statistics, the robustness of the median refers to the property that if you compute the median on a data-set of observations drawn from a uni-modal, continuous model and then replace less than half of these observations by arbitrary values, the value of the median computed on the contaminated data is close to  the value you would have had had you computed it on the original (uncontaminated) data-set.
Then, it is easy to show that the estimation strategy you propose in the paragraph I quoted above is definitely *not* robust in the sense of how the word is typically understood for the median.

I'm wholly unfamiliar with Bayesian analysis. However, I was wondering what is wrong with the following strategy as it seems simple, effective and yet has not been considered in the other answers. The prior is that the good part of the data is drawn from a symmetric distribution $F$ and that the rate of contamination is less than half. Then, a simple strategy would be to:

1. compute the median/mad of your dataset. Then compute:
   $$z_i=\frac{|x_i-\mbox{med}(x)|}{\mbox{mad}(x)}$$
2. exclude the observations for which $z_i>q_{\alpha}(z|x\sim F)$ (this is the $\alpha$ quantile of the distribution of $z$ when $x\sim F$). This quantity is avalaible for many choice of $F$ and can be bootstrapped for the others.
3. Run a (usual, non-robust) Bayesian analysis on the non-rejected observations.

## EDIT:

Thanks to the OP for providing a self contained R 
code to conduct a bonna fide bayesian analysis of the 
problem.

the code below compares the the bayesian approach suggested by the O.P. to 
 it's alternative from the robust statistics literature (e.g. the fitting method proposed by Gauss for the case where the data may contain as much as $n/2-2$ 
outliers and the distribution of the good part of the data is Gaussian).

central part of the data is $\mathcal{N}(1000,1)$:

```
n<-100
set.seed(123)
y<-rnorm(n,1000,1)
```

Add some amount of contaminants:

```
y[1:30]<-y[1:30]/100-1000 
w<-rep(0,n)
w[1:30]<-1
```

the index w takes value 1 for the outliers. I begin with the approach 
 suggested by the O.P.:

```
library("rjags")
model_string<-"model{
  for(i in 1:length(y)){
    y[i]~dt(mu,inv_s2,nu)
  }
  mu~dnorm(0,0.00001)
  inv_s2~dgamma(0.0001,0.0001)
  s<-1/sqrt(inv_s2)
  nu~dexp(1/30) 
}"

model<-jags.model(textConnection(model_string),list(y=y))
mcmc_samples<-coda.samples(model,"mu",n.iter=1000)
print(summary(mcmc_samples)$statistics[1:2])
summary(mcmc_samples)
```

I get:

```
     Mean        SD 
384.2283  97.0445
```

and:

```
2. Quantiles for each variable:

 2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% 
184.6 324.3 384.7 448.4 577.7
```

(quiet far thus from the target values)

For the robust method,

```
z<-abs(y-median(y))/mad(y)
th<-max(abs(rnorm(length(y))))
print(c(mean(y[which(z<=th)]),sd(y[which(z<=th)])))
```

one gets:

```
 1000.149 0.8827613
```

(very close to the target values)

The second result is much closer to the real values. 
But it gets worst. If we classify as outliers those observations
 for which the estimated $z$-score is larger than `th` (remember that the 
prior is that $F$ is Gaussian)  then the bayesian approach finds that *all* the observations are outliers (the robust procedure, in contrast, flags all and only the outliers as such). This also implies that if you were to run a usual (non-robust) bayesian analysis on the data not classified as outliers by the robust procedure, you should do fine (e.g. fulfil the objectives  stated in your question).
This is just an example, but it's actually fairly straightforward to 
show that (and it can done formally, see for example, in chapter 2 of [1]) the parameters of a student $t$ distribution fitted to contaminated data cannot be depended upon to reveal the outliers.

- [1]Ricardo A. Maronna, Douglas R. Martin, Victor J. Yohai (2006). Robust Statistics: Theory and Methods (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics).
- Huber, P. J. (1981). Robust Statistics. New York: John Wiley and Sons.

Comment: Well, the t is often proposed as a robust alternative to the normal distribution. I don't know if this is in the weak sense or not. See for example: Lange, K. L., Little, R. J., & Taylor, J. M. (1989). Robust statistical modeling using the t distribution. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 84(408), 881-896. [pdf](http://statistics.ucla.edu/system/resources/BAhbBlsHOgZmSSJVMjAxMi8wNS8zMC8xNV8zMV80Ml82MzFfUm9idXN0X1N0YXRpc3RpY2FsX01vZGVsaW5nX1VzaW5nX3RoZV90X0Rpc3RyaWJ1dGlvbi5wZGYGOgZFVA/Robust%20Statistical%20Modeling%20Using%20the%20t-%20Distribution.pdf)

Comment: This is the weak sense. If you have an R code that implements the procedure you suggest, I ll be happy to illustrate my answer with an example. otherwise you can get more explanation in chapter 2 of [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0470010940) textbook.

Comment: The procedure I suggest is basically described here: http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/BEST/ including R code. I will have to think about your solution! It does not, however, seem Bayesian in the sense that it does not model all the data, just the subset that "survives" step 2.

Comment: I thank you for your interesting discussion! Your answer is not that I seek, however, because (1) you don't describe a Bayesian procedure, you describe more of a data preparation step for how to remove outliers (2) your procedure does not result in a consistent estimator of SD, that is, if you sample from a normal distribution and the number of datapoints $ \rightarrow \infty$ you will not approach the "true" SD, rather your estimate will be a bit low. I also don't completely buy your definition of robust (your definition is not how I have seen it in most Bayesian literature I've come across)

Comment: `Data <- rnorm(9999999, sd=1000);

z<-abs(Data-median(Data))/mad(Data);
print(c(mean(Data[which(z<=3)]),sd(Data[which(z<=3)])));`
`[1]   0.7226 987.2233`

Repeated runs consistenly results in an estimated SD below 990. I'm aware of (and perhaps unduly impressed by) the robust literature and what I wan't to know is how to get some of the same benefits in a Bayesian framework.

Comment: This is trivially fixed (I've edited my post to make it more clear what is meant there). For the rest of your comment, It's still much closer to the true value than the estimate from the bayesian approach. Maybe you can append to your question a self contained example of what you call bayesian analysis (it's better that questions be self contained).

Comment: I have now done so!

Comment: @RasmusBååth: many thanks! I think the answer is much better for it.

Comment: Yes, I see that my procedure does not retrieve the underlying parameter values in your example well. But it remains that you have not proposed a robust Bayesian model, right? Should I interpret your answer as that robustness with respect to a scale parameter is impossible within a Bayesian framework?

Comment: I think, it depends on how you define a Bayesian model. If you insist on modeling the outliers, then, I submit to you robustness is not what you are after --you want something more like (unsupervised) clustering. Robustness as the term is understood in robust statistics deals with estimators that can withstand arbitrary configurations of outliers (even outliers that don't have a pdf), so long as they constitute less than half of the data.

Comment: You do realise the median is the Bayesian estimator under a Laplace distribution for the errors.  This goes against you "robust and bayesian" being incompatible.

Comment: i am completely ignorant of these things. It was not my claim that the median is not bayesian, it was Rasmus's (that also why I used the word "apparently" with a link to his comment.

Answer (score 1):

In bayesian analysis using the [inverse Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) as a prior for the precision (the inverse of the variance) is a common choice. Or the inverse Wishart distribution for multivariate models. Adding a prior on the variance improves robustness against outliers.

There is a nice paper by Andrew Gelman: "Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models" where he discusses what good choices for the priors on the variances can be.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see how this answers the question. I did not ask for a robust prior, but rather for a robust *model*.

Answer (score 0):

A robust estimator for the location parameter $\mu$ of some dataset of size $N$ is obtained when one assigns a Jeffreys prior to the variance $\sigma^2$ of the normal distribution, and computes the marginal for $\mu$, yielding a $t$ distribution with $N$ degrees of freedom.

Similarly, if you want a robust estimator for the standard deviation $\sigma$ of some data $D$, we can do the following:

First, we suppose that the data is normally distributed when its mean and standard deviation are known. Therefore,
$$\left.D\right|_{\mu,\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
and if $D \equiv (d_1,\ldots,d_N)$ then
$$p(D|\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma)^N} \exp\left(-\frac{N}{2\sigma^2}\left((m-\mu^2)+s^2\right)\right)$$
where the sufficient statistics $m$ and $s^2$ are
$$m=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N d_i \quad s^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N d_i^2 - m^2$$
In addition, using Bayes' theorem, we have
$$p(\mu,\sigma^2|D) \propto p(D|\mu,\sigma^2) p(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
A convenient prior for $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the [Normal-invese-gamma family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-gamma_distribution), which covers a wide range of shapes and is conjugate to this likelihood. This means that the posterior distribution $p(\mu,\sigma^2|D)$ still belongs to the normal-inverse-gamma family, and its marginal $p(\sigma^2|D)$ is an [inverse gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_gamma_distribution) parameterized as
$$\left.\sigma^2\right|_{D} \sim \mathcal{IG}\left(\alpha+N/2,2\beta+Ns^2\right) \qquad \alpha,\beta>0$$
From this distribution, we can take the mode, which will give us an estimator for $\sigma^2$. This estimator will be more or less tolerant to small excursions from misspecifications on the model by varying $\alpha$ and/or $\beta$. The variance of this distribution will then provide some indication on the fault-tolerance of the estimate. Since the tails of the inverse gamma are semi-heavy, you get the kind of behaviour you would expect from the $t$ distribution estimate for $\mu$ that you mention.

Comment: "A robust estimator for the location parameter μ of some dataset of size N is obtained when one assigns a Jeffreys prior to the variance $σ^2$ of the normal distribution." Isn't this Normal model you describe a typical example of a **non-robust** model? That is, a single value that is off can have **great** influence on the parameters of the model. There is a big difference between the posterior over the mean being a t-distribution (as in your case) and the distribution *for the data* being a t-distribution (as is a common example of a robust Bayesian model for estimating the mean).

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by robust. What you are saying right now is that you would like robustness wrt data. What I was proposing was robustness wrt model mis-specification. They are both different types of robustness.

Comment: I would say that the examples I gave, [MAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) and [using a t distribution as the distribution for the data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Robust_parametric_modeling) are examples of robustness with respect to data.

Comment: I would say Rasmus is right and so would Gelman er al in BDA3, as would a basic understanding that th t distribution has fatter tails than the normal for the same location parameter

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the discussion from the original question. Rasmus when you say robustness I am sure you mean in the data (outliers, not miss-specification of distributions).  I will take the distribution of the data to be Laplace distribution instead of a t-distribution, then as in normal regression where we model the mean, here we will model the median (very robust) aka median regression (we all know). Let the model be:

$Y=\beta X+\epsilon$, $\epsilon$ has laplace$(0,$$\sigma^2)$.

Of course our goal is to estimate model parameters. We expect our priors to be vague to have an objective model. The model at hand has a posterior of the form $f(\beta,\sigma,Y,X)$. Giving $\beta$ a normal prior with large variance makes such a prior vague and a chis-squared prior with **small** degrees of freedom to mimic a jeffrey's prior(vague prior) is given to to $\sigma^2$. With a Gibbs sampler what happens? normal prior+laplace likehood=???? we do know. Also chi-square prior +laplace likelihood=??? we do not know the distribution. Fortunately for us there is a theorem in (Aslan,2010) that transforms a laplace likelihood to a scale mixture of normal distributions which then enable us to enjoy the conjugate properties of our priors. I think the whole process described is fully robust in terms of outliers. In a multivariate setting chi-square becomes a a wishart distribution, and we use multivariate laplace and normal distributions.

Comment: Your solution seems to be focused on robust estimation of the location(mean/median). My question was rather about estimation of scale with the property of consistency with respect to retrieving the SD when the data generating distribution actually is normal.

Comment: With a robust estimate of the location, the scale as function of the location immediately benefits from the robustness of the location. There is no other way of making the scale robust.

Comment: Anyway I must say I am eagerly waiting to see how this problem will be tackled most especially with a normal distribution as you emphasized.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have $K$ groups and you want to model the distribution of their sample variances, perhaps in relation to some covariates $\bf{x}$. That is, suppose that your data point for group $k \in {1 \ldots K}$ is $\textrm{Var}(y_k) \in [0, \infty)$. The question here is, "What is a robust model for the likelihood of the sample variance?" One way to approach this is to model the transformed data $\textrm{ln}[\textrm{Var}(y_k)]$ as coming from a $t$ distribution, which as you have already mentioned is a robust version of the normal distribution. If you don't feel like assuming that the transformed variance is approximately normal as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then you could choose a probability distribution with positive real support that is known to have heavy tails compared to another distribution with the same location. For example, there is [a recent answer to a question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86431/7616) about whether the lognormal or gamma distribution has heavier tails, and it turns out that the lognormal distribution does (thanks to [@Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b) for that contribution). In addition, you could explore the half-Cauchy family.

Similar reasoning applies if instead you are assigning a prior distribution over a scale parameter for a normal distribution. Tangentially, the lognormal and inverse-gamma distributions are not advisable if you want to form a boundary avoiding prior for the purposes of posterior mode approximation because they peak sharply if you parameterize them so that the mode is near zero. See BDA3 chapter 13 for discussion. So in addition to identifying a robust model in terms of tail thickness, keep in mind that kurtosis may matter to your inference, too.

I hope this helps you as much as your answer to one of my recent questions helped me.

Comment: My question was about the situation when you have one group and how to robustly estimate the scale of that group. In the case of outliers I don't believe the sample variance is considered robust.

Comment: If you have one group, and you are estimating its normal distribution, then your question applies to the form of the prior over its scale parameter. As my answer implies, you can use a t distribution over its log transformation or choose a fat tailed distribution with positive real support, being careful about other aspects of that distribution such as its kurtosis. Bottom line, if you wan a robust model for a scale parameter, use a t distribution over its log transform or some other fat tailed distribution.