# Power of Uniform Distribution?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

In the Bayesian analysis, $\mathtt{rjags}$ in particular, it is very frequent to see the code:

```
sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
sigma.1 <- pow(sigma, -2)
```

But, what does this mean? Is this meaning that $\sigma\sim Unif(0.01, 100)$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma^{-2}$ and we are doing a transformation of the uniform distribution? As I do the transformation, I got the pdf of $\sigma_1$ to be $\frac{y}{50}$ over $(100^{-2}, +\infty)$, which indeed is not a valid density if I did not make any mistake in my calculations.

Any explanations? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a link to such a code ?

Comment: @peuhp http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/data/dugongsNL_BUGS.txt Here is an example. See the model part.

Comment: You got confused in the change of variable, the Jacobian returns $\sigma_1^{-3/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the code because of the parametrisation used in Bugs and Jags syntax. In Jags and Bugs, the normal density as well as other location/scale distributions are parametrized such as e.g.

```
dnorm(location,precision)
```

where precision is the precision i.e. by definition $1/\sigma^2$ and generally denoted as $\tau$. So the prior on $\sigma$ is uniform (which has its limits but it is another question see e.g. [Weakly informative prior distributions for scale parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/weakly-informative-prior-distributions-for-scale-parameters/6506))