# Can I use mean ± 95% CI to present results in paper writing?

Tags: confidence-interval

Most scientific papers present data using mean (95%CI lower bound, 95%CI upper bound) but I have not seen mean ± 95% CI (upper bound - mean). Can I use the latter to present my results?

e.g.,

mean = 1.0
CIlb = 0.8
CIub = 1.2

Can I present the result as 1 ± 0.2 （mean ± 95%CI）or must I present as 1.0 (0.8, 1.2)?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: yes, I just added one

Comment: You can do that... if the CI is symmetric.

Comment: @user2974951 How is the poor reader supposed to understand either expression, exactly?  There appear to be multiple reasonable interpretations of them, and "mean ± 95%CI," which explicitly appears to sum a *number* with an *interval about that number* is either nonsensical or wrong.

Comment: I suspect that [credible intervals would serve much better](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/85582) for the kind of result summary that you have in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all CIs are symmetrical, so the tradition is to report a confidence interval as an interval ("from LL to UL", or "LL,UL")

In your example, the CI is symmetrical so the plus/minus nomenclature is not ambiguous and is easy to understand. But it is not standard. You describe it as "mean ± 95% CI" but you really mean "mean ± margin of error", which is a better way to describe your syntax.