# How do I tell when and why to use specific statistical measures?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, intuition

I've taken a few probability classes and now understand how to calculate some statistical measures like mean and confidence intervals.  What I don't know is the what, when, and why of using these measures for specific situations.  I'm hoping to put together a good collection of each of these measures, what they're used for, and what situations these are good to use.  Specifically I'm looking for these (but not limited to):

- Mean (average)
- Standard Deviation
- [Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/intuitive-explanation-of-variance-and-moment-in-probability)
- Confidence Intervals
- Median

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General Advice

- Start analysing data and reading the analyses of other researchers.
  This should assist you in mapping statistical techniques onto data analytic problems.
- Read some applied statistics textbooks related to a domain that you are interested in.
- If you have specific questions (e.g., when would you report the SD versus the variance? or when would you use the median rather than the mean), do a search and see if a question already exists on the site. If no such question exists, ask it here.

#### Mean, SD, Var, CI, Median

I'd broadly classify the five things you mentioned into

- Measures of central tendency: Mean, Median

  - There are questions on this site that discuss when to use mean versus median [such as this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/why-is-median-age-a-better-statistic-than-mean-age).
- Measures of spread: SD, Var
- Measures of confidence in parameter estimation: CI