# How is it possible for the arithmetic mean of a distribution to be off-center?

Tags: distributions, mean, descriptive-statistics

This is a question I recently saw on a test:

"Consider the following statement: More than 65% of the residents of Los Angeles earn less than the average wage for that city. Could this statement be correct? If so, how? If not, why not?"

The answer I put was that this statement could be correct because the mean isn't always centered perfectly, and nothing else (and I actually got full credit for this). After the test, however, I've had trouble understanding *how* the mean isn't always centered perfectly, because it evenly sums all the values and divides it by the number of values in the distribution. I think it could have something to do with skews and outliers, but I'm not completely sure.

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: What would happen to the average wage if, say, Jeff Bezos were to move into the city?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/ for a closely related thread.

Comment: Check the distinction between the mean and the median of a population.

Comment: Average is meant to mean median. Not surprising as income is skewed. Classic problem  of using terms without defining them.

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2547.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the "mean" with the "median". There are always half members on each side of the "median", not the "mean".

To illustrate, as an example, consider a group of 100 people, among them 35 have higher incomes, say, each has 1 million dollars per year, while other 65 have lower incomes, each has 0.1 million dollars per year. The mean (average) income for each person then is (35+6.5)/100 = 0.415 millions. Obviously, 65% of the group have their incomes below the mean.