# Bayesian statistics tutorial

Tags: bayesian, references

I am trying to get upto speed in Bayesian Statistics. I have a little bit of stats background (STAT 101) but not too much - I think I can understand prior, posterior, and likelihood :D.

I don't want to read a Bayesian textbook just yet.
I'd prefer to read from a source (website preferred) that will ramp me up quickly. Something like [this](http://www.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/bayescourse.pdf), but that has more details.

Any advice?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a place to start:

ftp://selab.janelia.org/pub/publications/Eddy-ATG3/Eddy-ATG3-reprint.pdf

http://blog.oscarbonilla.com/2009/05/visualizing-bayes-theorem/

http://yudkowsky.net/rational/bayes

http://www.math.umass.edu/~lavine/whatisbayes.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability

[Tutorial_on_Bayesian_Statistics_and_Clinical_Trials](http://gistsupport.medshelf.org/Marina%27s_Tutorial_on_Bayesian_Statistics_and_Clinical_Trials)

Comment: I'm just wondering if anyone else noticed that the values at the top of page 2 of the 4th link (whatisbayes.pdf) are a little farther off than simple rounding error?  I'm getting about 0.040, 0.097, 0.138, 0.139.

Comment: The first link doesn't seem to open for me on Safari or Firefox on my school's network, so I tried looking for an alternative. The paper is titled "What is Bayesian statistics?" by Sean R Eddy. Here's another link that worked for me: http://eddylab.org/publications/Eddy-ATG3/Eddy-ATG3-reprint.pdf

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to try a few learn by examples, you may be interested in "[Bayesian Computation in R](http://bayes.bgsu.edu/bcwr/)" by Jim Albert.

Its related R package is called LearnBayes.

Answer (score 5):

Some more depth:

- http://math.tut.fi/~piche/bayes/notes01.pdf covers Bayes' theorem
- https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/bayes/bayes.pdf and
- http://www-personal.une.edu.au/~jvanderw/Introduction_to_Bayesian_Statistics1.pdf are more about statistical applications

Answer (score 5):

These aren't complete tutorials on Bayesian statistics, but rather isolated explanations of individual concepts that I like. Just thought I'd add in case it helps.

- http://lesswrong.com/lw/2b0/bayes_theorem_illustrated_my_way - Graphical explanation of Bayes' theorem.
- [What's the difference between a confidence interval and a credible interval?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval/2287#2287) - Great example of the difference between confidence intervals and Bayesian credible intervals (and of the difference between frequentist statistics and Bayesian statistics in general).
- http://behind-the-enemy-lines.blogspot.com/2008/01/are-you-bayesian-or-frequentist-or.html - A simple example of how frequentists and Bayesians approach a problem differently, and how it leads to a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a post on [getting started with JAGS for Bayesian modelling](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/getting-started-with-jags-rjags-and.html). If you're keen to get started quickly then playing around with some variant of BUGS, such as JAGS, is a practical way to get started.

To quote the abstract of [the post](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/getting-started-with-jags-rjags-and.html)

> This post provides links to various resources on getting started with
>   Bayesian modelling using JAGS and R. It discusses: (1) what is JAGS;
>   (2) why you might want to perform Bayesian modelling using JAGS; (3)
>   how to install JAGS; (4) where to find further information on JAGS;
>   (5) where to find examples of JAGS scripts in action; (6) where to ask
>   questions; and (7) some interesting psychological applications of
>   Bayesian modelling.

In particular, you may find it useful to study some of the example scripts mentioned in the post.

Comment: Jeromy, your blog is a wonderful resource.

Answer (score 2):

You could try '[Teaching Bayesian Reasoning In Less Than Two Hours](https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/xge-1303380.pdf)'.

Comment: Unfortunately, Lynch's book is not completely reliable, as shown by [this other question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160017/7224).

Answer (score 2):

The [Bayes' rule guide on Arbital](https://arbital.com/p/bayes_rule/) is the best resource I've ever found by a good margin.

I like how they emphasize the odds form, include good visualizations, talk about how Bayesianism relates to philosophy, and include different learning paths depending on your background and interests.