# Free PDF for Bayes with R, similar to Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, bayesian, references

Is there a good book/pdf similar to "Elements of Statistical Learning" that's available for free online, that deals with Bayesian statistics, ideally with code for `R`?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7351/bayesian-statistics-tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, given that you asked for something similar to the elements, I'm going to assume that you are of a machine learning bent.

Therefore, I would suggest the following:

[Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/090310.pdf)

Additionally, if you are looking for something a little more introductory, I would suggest [Think Bayes](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/)

Comment: That's correct about the ML bent.  Great suggestions. Thank you.