# Probability statement with a confidence interval

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Suppose you construct a 95% confidence interval on a mean.  Can you state that there is a 97.5% probability that the true population mean lies below the CI upper bound and that there is a 97.5% probability that the true population mean lies above the CI lower bound?

Comment: [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval) may be helpful.

Comment: There are actually two reasons why the answer is 'no' in general. The first is given in Alexis' answer and SeanEaster's link. The second reason is that $1-\alpha$ confidence intervals do not *necessarily* put exactly $\alpha/2$ in each tail. Indeed when dealing with a discrete parameter, a CI for it generally can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The **confidence interval** (specifically this beast: $\bar{x} \pm z_{(1-\text{CL})/2}\hat{\sigma}_{\mu}$, where CL is the confidence level) is **not** a statement about the probability of the mean, $\mu$, which either **is** or **is not** contained within any specific interval with no possibility of both conditions obtaining. The substantive meaning of the frequentist confidence interval does not really reduce beyond:

If you repeated the study that produced your sample data *many, many* times so that you gathered many many samples of size $N$ you would expect that the CL% confidence intervals constructed on the means of each of those samples would contain the true population mean CL% of the time.

Of course, there are other kinds of estimation and inference intervals with different substantive meanings.

Comment: Suppose you have a set of data, compute the sample mean and the CL% confidence interval on the mean. What does the single CI that you have tell you, and what statement can you make with the single CI that you have?

Comment: You can say you are *this confident*, where confident has the meaning I gave in my second paragraph. It's not especially pretty. :\ That said, it is a way of evaluating $\sigma_{\mu}$, which, if $\hat{\sigma}_{\mu} \approx \sigma_{\mu}$ is true, should give you an idea of the trustworthiness of $\bar{x}$ as an estimate of $\mu$... where "trustworthiness" is a synonym for "confidence." Sorry, it just doesn't get much better.

Comment: OK thanks.  So if I understand you correctly, you cannot say that there is a 95% chance that the single confidence interval you have contains the mean?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Alexis is it possible to make a simulation that proves so?

Comment: @mihagazvoda No that is just plain frequentist logic: either your single confidence interval **does contain** $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ or it **does *not* contain** $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ **.** Assume you calculate a mean of 6 and a 95%CI for $\mu$ to be 3, 9. If $\mu$ actually equals 10 there is a 0 probability that your CI contains it. If $\mu$ actually equals 4.5, there is probability 1 that your CI contains it. **Once you have calculated a CI, it either *does* or *does not* contain your population statistic of interest.**

Comment: @Alexis I understand. But - are there any practical consequences if you interpret it as a Bayesian credible interval (because a lot of people do)? Can you give me an example that will show that you come to the wrong conclusion/result if you use the wrong interpretation?

Comment: @mihagazvoda Post that as a separate question!

Comment: @Alexis Here you go: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552783/practical-consequences-of-wrong-interpretation-of-confidence-intervals