# Confidence and credible interval: cases

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, inference, intuition, credible-interval

I am having difficulties in understanding these two approaches.

Let's say given the data I compute both confidence and credible interval, then what is the intuition/interpretation of having:

1. Big CI and small CR
2. Small CI and big CR
3. Both big or both small and they overlap
4. They do not overlap (not sure if it's possible)

Comment: Here is a related, albeit slightly different [question on comparing CIs and CrIs](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval).