# Confidence intervals - how to interpret and report

Tags: confidence-interval

Just to state that I don't belong to the statistics field or something related  (I am medical scientist). I've been trying to understand more about the confidence interval and how to interpret it for biological studies (in case of biological experiments). In this case, I was advised to report confidence intervals in order to reinforce my statistical tests and consequently the results achieved. Could anyone help me with any reference or a brief explanation how to apply confidence intervals in biological experiments and how they can be interpreted based on confidence intervals?

Thanks a lot

Julian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a confidence interval and a credible interval?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval)

Comment: This question might also be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26450

Comment: You may need to ask a more specific question to distinguish it more clearly from the indicated posts.