# credible interval in bayes are higher than the nominal level

Tags: bayesian, credible-interval

When I fitted the nonlinear regression using the openbugs, and calculated the 95% credible interval of the coefficient through the high density interval, I found that the total number of the credible interval including the true vales is higher than 95%, about 98%. What is the probably reason for this ?

Comment: Are you asking about the frequentist properties of your credible region?

Comment: @innisfree  I have read some books about the bayes, and it says the credible interval should match the nominal level to evaluate the method. So I tried to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this sort of behaviour before when you do simulations and the assumed true value for the simulations is in the centre of reasonably informative priors (e.g. you have a regression coefficient with a N(0, 1) prior and simulate it as being 0). In contrast,  if you sample simulation scenarios from your priors, you should on average get a coverage frequency that matches the nominal level. I.e. the reason is likely that you "sample" (or just fix them) parameter values from a much more narrow distribution at/ close to the centre of your prior.

Comment: So you mean that the the true value is in the centre of my prior distribution? I will try some different true value. It is true that my prior distribution is narrow because I know that one of the regression coefficients is from 0 to 1, and it's impossible to be lower than 0 or higher than 1. So I restrict it's prior distribution to be uniform distribution(0,1) so that I can get a posterior distribution that is between 0 to 1. Does this influence its credible interval? And does this affect the  coverage frequency? If it cannot match the nomial level, can we say the method is right?

Comment: Yes, i would guess that a true value of 0.5 would give you above nominal coverage, and of course a true value of 1.001 should get you 0% coverage for that particular parameter. As said, simulating with parameter values sampled from the prior should give you exact coverage - that's what you can and should have. In a sense above nominal coverage is not a problem,  is it? If course,  at the edge of the prior you might get below nominal coverage.

Comment: I always thought I need to set the true value to be fixed for the simulation. So you mean I can sample the true value from the prior each time and generate data, calculate its coverage interval?But that will be difficult to explain it because I don't know the true value. I am confused with the situation when the coefficient in the real world is restrict to a range. And you are right, I get below nominal coverage at the edge of the prior.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice posting that contains this already on Stack Exchange.  Credible intervals are not confidence intervals.  Read [What's the difference between a confidence interval and a credible interval?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval).

Bayesian credible intervals can have better or worse coverage properties than confidence intervals.  Good priors are equivalent to adding to the sample, which makes the intervals narrower and improves coverage.