# How can one perform a two-group binomial power analysis without using normal approximations?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, statistical-power

I would like to do power analyses for hypothesis tests of (non-)equality of proportions in which the proportions are *very* small.  I would like to do so **without** using normal (or Poisson) approximations of the binomial distribution.  There are several general types of power questions I'd like to be able to address.

1. *Post-hoc*:  Given $\Pr_1$ (probability of a success in group 1) and $\Pr_2$ and $N_1$ (sample size group 1) and $N_2$ to calculate the power of the design given $\alpha$.
2. *A priori* solve for $N$ given $\alpha$, the ratio $N_1\over{N_2}$, $1 - \beta$ (power), $\alpha$, $\Pr_1$, and an expected $\Pr_2$
3. *A priori* solve for $1 - \beta$ given $\alpha, N_1, N_2, \Pr_1$, and $\Pr_2$.

An ideal response would include R code and point out any other givens that I forgot to point out.  A simulation approach is not a suitable response due to the small proportions.  With your solution, please also mention what kind of statistical test it is applicable to.

Comment: One very general way to deal w/ these is via simulation. See, e.g., my answer here: [simulation of logistic regression power analysis designed experiments](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940//35994#35994).

Comment: I didn't think simulations would be a fruitful approach when proportions are *very* small (on the order of 1 in 50,000 or less).

Comment: I'm also not clear on how hypothetical instances where a marginal proportion is 0 should be treated.

Comment: @RusselS.Pierce, you're right, simulations become more unwieldy the closer the proportions get to the boundaries. That's because power (viz, whether an iteration is 'significant') is a Bernoulli.

Comment: This is relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235750/experimental-design-on-testing-proportions/270076#270076      *how small* do you imagine $p$ can be?

Comment: @kjetil b Halverson would you please elaborate re: relevance?

Comment: Well, it analyzes two-sample binomial comparisons.  You can adapt code from there to make plots for the case where both $p$'s are very small. You say about 1/50000 (or even smaller) then you cannot relly expect to learn much if not $n$ is at least around 150000.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer.  It is a community wiki that people may edit as they look for the answer.

[G*power 3](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/abteilungen/aap/gpower3/) can perform (approximations) of these analyses (per [this site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/gpower/indeppropor1.htm)).  The [canonical reference for that software](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/abteilungen/aap/gpower3/download-and-register/Dokumente/GPower3-BRM-Paper.pdf) provides a reference for performing (at least some) of these types of power analyses as Cohen, 1988 chapter 6 (and 7) as does [this example](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/dae/proportionpow.htm) using SAS.  The exact equations/procedures may be available from that source.  However, the approximations appear to break down at small probabilities.

Comment: Why isnt' this an answer? It looks like one to me...

Comment: I suppose it is, the GPower reference does claim that "Cohen’s(1988) effectsize g is used and exact power values based on the binomial distribution are calculated".  I suppose I was just holding out hope for actual equations.

Comment: It actually isn't.  The referred to claim is not relevant to the 2 groups binomial case.