# Possible to have overlapping 95 CIs for two means but 95 CI for difference between the means does not include zero?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I am not sure if I've made a computational error, am failing to think something through (too late in the day), or just really don't understand confidence intervals as much as I was hoping I did, but I ran a linear model with Condition as a predictor (2 groups) and the slope representing the group difference was significantly different from zero:

```
b = 0.10599, t = 2.043, p = 0.045, 95% CIs [0.0023, 0.21]
```

However, when I compute the CIs for the two group means they overlap:

```
Experimental: M = .32, 95% CIs [.24, .39]

Control: M = .21, 95% CIs [.14, .28].
```

What's going on? The overlapping CIs suggest to me that the means aren't significantly different, but I thought testing whether the mean difference differs significantly from zero is the same as testing whether the means differ significantly from each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18215/28500) for an explanation of the relation between overlapping confidence intervals and significance tests for the difference between 2 groups. No overlap of 95% confidence intervals is much too stringent a test for the difference between the two means at p = 0.05. *Each* mean value would be in the space outside *its own* 95% CI only a fraction of 0.05 of the time in repeated samplings. Crudely, requiring lack of overlap of the two 95% might be thought of as requiring this restriction to hold simultaneously for *both* mean values, which would occur only (0.05)^2 = 0.0025 fraction of the time. More detailed calculations on the linked page show that non-overlap of 95% CIs is about equivalent to a p = 0.005 test for the difference between the 2 means, under reasonable assumptions.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll bet that this is one reason why people tend to use SE bars instead of CIs for bar charts!

Comment: Those who tend to use bar charts a lot probably haven't thought much about what error bars to display, other than that SEs are smaller. Showing non-overlap of 83% CI would approximately be equivalent to p = 0.05 for a difference in means according to the page I linked in my answer, but I'm unaware of any groundswell of support for such displays.

Comment: I've heard Geoff Cummings talk about shifting towards using CIs instead of null hypothesis testing, and I believe he and others have argued that CIs should be displayed in bar charts instead of SEs. I would do this if there was a good reason to, but I worry that others may get confused as I did. (I could avoid the bar chart altogether but for some reason people like to see them.)