# Cohen's d and the use of the standard deviation of the control group

Tags: effect-size

In this paper

Cumming, G. (2014). The new statistics: Why and how. Psychological science, 25(1), 7-29.

one can read this about Cohens' d:

> For two independent groups, if we assume homogeneity of variance, the  pooled standard deviation within groups, $s_p$, is our standardizer,  just  as  we  use  for  the  independent-groups  t test. If we suspect the treatment notably affects variability,  we  might  prefer  the  control  population’s  standard   deviation, estimated by $s_C$ (the control group’s standard  deviation), as the standardizer.

I was wondering why one should prefer the standard deviation of the control group when the treatment affects variability and whether they are references that justify this point.

Comment: Relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250269/cumming-2008-claims-that-distribution-of-p-values-obtained-in-replications-dep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of Cohen's $d$ is to standardize the effect in terms of the natural variation on that outcome, that is, variation *without* the influence of the treatment. This is the basis of the preference for the control standard deviation and not the treatment standard deviation. However, Hedges' did some work in the early/mid 1980s that showed that the pooled standard deviation provides a better estimate of the population standard deviation (this is what we really want) than the control group standard deviation unless the treatment has a rather large effect on outcome variability.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Glass'_%CE%94), the effect size is called Glass' $\Delta$

and the reason to use it proposed by Glass is that

> if several treatments were compared to the control group it would be
>   better to use just the standard deviation computed from the control
>   group, so that effect sizes would not differ under equal means and
>   different variances.