# Question regarding Taleb's meta-probability of p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

There has been [one question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220903/high-variance-of-the-distribution-of-p-values-an-argument-in-taleb-2016) here regarding Taleb's article [The Meta-Distribution of Standard P-Values](http://fooledbyrandomness.com/pvalues.pdf). I have a somewhat different question, at the very end of the article Taleb claims that:

> • One can safely see that under such stochasticity for
>   the realizations of p-values and the distribution of its
>   minimum, to get what people mean by 5% confidence (and the inferences they get from it), they need a p-value
>   of at least one order of magnitude smaller.

On figure 2, there is a somewhat similar sounding claim, particularly the part "illusions of statistical significance":

> Fig. 2. The probability distribution of a one-tailed p-value with expected
>   value .11 generated by Monte Carlo (histogram) as well as analytically with
>   ϕ(.) (the solid line). We draw all possible subsamples from an ensemble with
>   given properties. The excessive skewness of the distribution makes the average
>   value considerably higher than most observations, hence causing illusions of
>   "statistical significance".

1. What does Taleb mean by these statement?
2. Is it correct that we should be using p-values order of magnitude lower to have "what people mean by 5% confidence"?