# How to test the statistical significance of the sampling distribution of the mean

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, sampling, mean

I need to test if the mean of the `sampling distribution of the mean`, which belongs to a normal distribution with mean = 0 and variance = 1, is significantly different from the mean of the original distribution.

How can I do it through a statistical test AND by looking at confidence intervals?

#

Assuming that I can use a t-test and that I already performed one with R, could you please give a simple example on how to double check my t-test's p-values by looking at the confidence intervals?

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want to know is how to do a t-test?

Comment: I can do a t-test with R. But I also desire to double check my p-values by looking at the confidence intervals. How can I do that?

Comment: It's the same thing...? A 5% test is always the same as 95% confidence band in this case...

Comment: yes @Repmat I know but I am curious to know how to 'perform a t-test' by looking at the values in the confidence intervals range. Even a simple and stupid example would be highly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The confidence interval is based on the distribution of your test statistic. In your case, I'd use a t-statistic. This statistic follows the Student's t-distribution. You can calculate a confidence interval via the inverse distribution function. In R this is `qt(q,v)` where `v` are the degrees of freedom (#samples - 1) and `q` is the quantile you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at a difference in means it is sometimes the case that  hypothesis testing (via a t-test) and looking at confidence intervals yield the same result. You still have to make sure that the sample sizes are comparable and that the sample variances are approximately equal. See [Relation between confidence interval and testing statistical hypothesis for t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18215/relation-between-confidence-interval-and-testing-statistical-hypothesis-for-t-te/18259#18259) for reference.

Comment: What Maximillian means is that if H0 is mean=0  rejecting the null hypothesis at the 5% level is the same as knowing that a 95% confidence interval does not contain 0.  We call this the 1-1 correspondence between hypothesis testing and confidence intervals.  This is a general result that applies to other tests and not just the t test. It also applies to any level of significance and not just 5%.