The rationale for when significance or null hypothesis testing is needed
Why do people sometimes claim that an effect is so huge and "obvious" that it does not warrant any inferential statistics calculation, even though the sample size is not large?
This is coming from a biological/medical field mostly out of laboratory designed experiments.
The following is an example of one such experiment

These are means + SDs. They usually reach the conclusion of "differences are too obvious, so no tests are needed" before sample CIs are even computed.
Can anyone share some references about this matter?

Where have these comments been made and in what context?

I have seen this happening mostly when discussing experimental results for molecular biology and pharmacology. For example, https://pasteboard.co/xp7MWIuPhlMI.jpg, some would say you don't need to test for the effect of drug B and drug A + B vs. control because they're "obviously" different than the control. I don't get that rationale.

In some cases this may have to do with background knowledge. As a statistician I have seen many situations where I thought testing is pointless because (for example) groups must be different by definition, correlation between two variables must be clearly positive and nonzero etc. (Obviously the difference is then not the result of the analysis but rather prior knowledge; this wouldn't explain why people claim this from the information in the sample only.) Also note that a good number of statisticians think that null hypothesis testing is flawed and never needed.

If it's just data like on the linked image, I can see that differences will be significant, but this doesn't really mean that "a test is not needed", it rather means that from experience I know what the test result will be without actually computing it.

@BioLeal might this be in relation to non-overlapping confidence intervals?  Some people often use this as justification for coming to the conclusion that two groups are statistically different with respect to the average outcome.

@DemetriPananos Interesting thought, but that is a sufficient (but not necessary) condition to reject the null hypothesis at the $\alpha$ corresponding to the confidence level, isn’t it?

@DemetriPananos Nope, they reach the "obvious differences no test needed" even before computing sample CIs, just by eyeballing the averages and dispersion.

@ChristianHennig "As a statistician I have seen many situations where I thought testing is pointless because (for example) groups must be different by definition" unfortunately there are cases where tests were performed anyway and the (meaningless) significant result presented as being of practical importance.  Common sense can be more important than the (false impression) of statistical rigor.

Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/2400/ . But sadly life is not always that easy

This question is well answered by @ChristianHennig's comment, but that is worth some expansions.
Statistical tests are useful when they allow some additional confidence in scientific inferences, but they do that by way of statistical inferences. The tests know nothing at all of the subject matter and that is often both important and overlooked.
For the system that gave the figure linked it is very likely that drugs A and B have been previously characterised by the investigators who published that figure as well as by others. The ability of drug B to elicit an increase in protein A levels in those particular cells (I'm guessing cells) might be well enough known that the response is not in question. Further, as Christian points out, it is obvious to any experienced eye that the means of the control and drug B bars are going to be 'statistically significant'. Making a statistical inference about the difference between the drug B bar and the control bar would likely offer no increased clarity to the interpretation of the overall results of the experiment.
My guess is that they scientific question for the experiment from which the figure has been taken relates to the interaction of effects of drug A and drug B. It is very likely a badly designed experiment for such a question, but a common enough design, unfortunately. With the principle of charity in mind I will assume that there are other relevant datasets in the paper from which that figure has been plucked.
If it has been repeatedly demonstrated that drug B increases protein A and you are interested in the potential interaction between drug B and drug A then the critical comparisons in that figure are between control and drug A alone (obviously 'not significant', but more on that later) and between drug B alone and the two drugs together (modestly 'significant' to my eye). I would be surprised if your claim of "differences too obvious no tests needed" is a fair description of the investigators' responses to those comparisons unless their scientific inferences are strongly supported by other experiments shown in that same paper.
Now, the obviously 'not significant' effect of drug A alone. That is inadequately demonstrated in that experiment no matter what statistical test has, or has not, been applied. The sample size is far too small to give us any confidence about the ability of drug A to elicit a change in protein A levels in that experiment. You can make sure that an effect size is too small to be found statistically significant simply by using a too small sample. If the scientific inferences of the experimenters hinge on drug A being ineffective alone then that might invalidate them entirely.
I said that the design of the experiment is inadequate to demonstrate synergy between drug A and drug B even though it is a common type of design. How should it be done, in my opinion? Well with far more extensive testing using the known features of the stimulus-response pathways in question. See this for an example from my own laboratory many years ago: https://bpspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1038/sj.bjp.0702435

Thank you for the clarifications. I wanted to know if there is support for claiming no tests are needed based on eyeballing the averages of the experiment at hands - only.

What sort of 'support' are you asking for? When statistical significance is not at issue, why do a test? If you do all of the tests will editors and reviewers claim that you need to do some sort of family-wise 'correction' for multiplicity? Scientific inferences do not always need assistance of statistical inferences.

Support meaning references on the subject. I agree that scientific inferences do not  always need assistance of statistical inferences, but I wanted to read more about how the line is drawn.

I don't have any references, and think it unlikely that there is much available on the topic. Further, I think that drawing a line anywhere is undesirable. Maybe it is a topic for a PhD with analysis of original scientific publications and interviews of scientists...

@BioLeal There cannot be a definition regarding where to draw the line, because it's an informal decision from looking at graphs. Defining a "line" would mean formalising it, in which case you could well compute the test. Which you could do anyway. It's nothing but a judgment call to say "it's so clear that no test is needed" and the only way to check this is really to run the test. (And the people who made the call have the egg in their faces if it goes wrong, so in your own work you may want to avoid this claim altogether.)

I think avoiding such claim is best, especially if one is adopting the Neyman-Pearson paradigm of hypothesis testing anyway.

@BioLeal Well, my advice is that you do not adopt the Neyman–Pearsonian paradigm if you are interested in scientific knowledge acquisition. It is probably the worst approach for that purpose. Seriously. See here:https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

I make my comments plus something an answer:

There are situations in which it is clear from background knowledge that the null hypothesis is neither realistic nor interesting (such as "no correlation between a country's GDP and its spending on public health"), in which case it is obviously pointless to test it. Note that Bayesian statistics can bring together prior information and the actual data, so that it may detect situations in which it seems a priori somewhat unlikely but not impossible that a certain hypothesis is true, same from looking at the data alone, but if you bring them together, it looks very clear that the hypothesis is wrong (this would not be a null hypothesis test, as the latter is run on the data alone). In such cases, the claim that a test is not needed is not argued from the data alone.

In many problems the issue of interest is not addressed by a hypothesis test, as it's not about ruling out some specific null hypothesis. (Still many researchers ask statisticians for significance tests in such situations.) For example you may have a ranking problem where you need to select a "winner"; you can do that without testing whether the winner is significantly better than one or all of the others (you may or may not be interested in also testing this).

There are differences that are so clear from looking at the data that every experienced statistician knows that if you compute the test, it will come out significant. The ones in the image linked in the question are of this kind (B and A+B vs. control). Sometimes, if confidence intervals are given, this becomes even clearer. But note that in these cases the point isn't that "there's no need for the test", rather one could say that the test can be done informally without actually doing the math. Also there is a mathematical relation between confidence intervals and tests, so arguably saying something from looking at confidence intervals is formally very similar to running a test, and in many cases even mathematically equivalent. If anybody claims such a thing, they better be sure that if somebody else actually computes the test on the same data, they arrive at the same result. To somebody without much data analytic experience I'd recommend to run the test anyway, but always ask yourself before doing that from looking at the data what result you expect. You will then learn when your expectations are wrong and why, and achieve some intuition in this way. For sure nobody should claim that "groups are clearly different", "correlation is clearly nonzero" etc. in cases in which a test when actually run gives an insignificant result (this is relative to the significance level of course; "no test is needed" should really only be claimed if it's in fact significant at any reasonable significance level in use). If for your own data you are not sure (maybe even if you are), run the test, and for sure feel encouraged to check in case somebody else claims this and you are not sure.

There is a controversy going on in statistics about the use of significance tests in general, with some claiming that they should not be used at all. There is broad agreement that significance tests are invalid in a number of situations in which they are in fact often used, such as after having done model selection on the same data (in fact that situation is somewhat more complicated because there are developments for valid tests in some such cases, and it also depends on how exactly the model selection has been done, but certain things that can often be seen such as interpreting tests of multiple regression coefficients after having removed insignificant variables are clearly invalid). Also if you run many tests, some will turn out significant even if there is nothing meaningful going on, so running a large battery of tests on your data and then claiming a meaningful discovery for every one that turns out significant is also invalid.



Regarding 4, NHSTs can be useful in instilling a minimal degree of self-skepticism.  They are most valuable when you get a non-significant result that causes you to rein in your enthusiasm about your research hypothesis before you make a silly claim in print! ;o)  Significant results of NHSTs are of more questionable value (IMHO).

@DikranMarsupial I don't disagree, however I'm not a fan of the abbreviation NHST, as some people seem to use this not for significance testing in general but for a rather problematic (and not necessarily unambiguously defined) "cookbookery" way of using and interpreting them in some literature, so that at the end of the day when somebody says NHST I'm not totally sure what exactly they're talking about.

I think "cookbookery" sums up exactly the sort of usage of statistical testing I had in mind!  It can still have some value, but it would be far better if users could move beyond recipies and have a better understanding of what they are doing (speaking as somewhat of an ex-chef myself! ;o)

The critical issue with your #4 is that the thing at issue is mostly the all-or-none 'significant'/'not significant' result of a Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis test (or the NHST thing, more often than not). Some people insist on not seeing a difference between Fisherian significance tests which yield an evidence encoding p-value and the other procedures that result in a decision on the basis of nearly exclusively the information in the data and statistical model. The Fisherian approach has much more in common with your preferred Bayesian than it does with Neyman–Pearsonian decision.

One scenario where this may be valid is when the $(1-\alpha)%$ confidence intervals of a statistic $\theta$ from 2 samples do not overlap; in such a scenario, a NHST will always be significant at the $\alpha$ level. p-values, and confidence intervals are basically 2 sides of the same coin.
Now, if there is substantial overlap between 2 CI's, you would then need to run some inferential test to be able to reach a decision.
Based on the example you share, it shows what I would think are confidence intervals (CI's) around the various means (control, A, B, A+B): A overlaps almost exactly with control, so we can conclude that the experiment did not show any difference between these 2. But the CI of B is way above, and the CI of A+B is even more so: these 2 are different from each other, and from control and A. No need for a formal test.
The term IOTT (Interocular Traumatic Test) has been attributed to Joe Berkson. See here: "you know what the data mean when the conclusion hits you between the eyes."
Or, of course, to cite xkcd: "Statistics tip: always try to get data that is good enough that you don't need to do any statistics on it". Cartoon here.
One (small) caveat: in your example, the IOTT performed at a minimum 3 comparisons (Control vs. A, B and A+B), maybe 4 (A+B vs. B). One could argue for multiple comparison corrections? But even with $(1-\alpha/4)$ CI's, the gaps are so large that the IOTT would still be valid.

Thank you. I can see that coming from confidence intervals not overlapping, even though in a multiple comparison setting, I remember that the CIs for the differences of means is more important than sample CIs. But, usually it's like "the conclusion hits between the eyes so you don't need to do any statistics on it" mentality.

For more details on this, you may want to look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423609/does-the-percentage-overlap-in-confidence-intervals-matter

And more fundamental explanation here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685796?seq=1
