# Standardized Distance with Confidence Intervals

Tags: standardization

I have two values $a$ and $b$ with 95% CIs (estimated via Bootstrap if that matters). I want to take a difference between them but I am not sure of a *meaningful* statistic.

If I had $\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_b$, I would do $\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{\sigma_a^2 + \sigma_b^2}}$ but (a) I do not readily have that, and (b) I am really much more interested in the 95% CI.

Is there a well-known meaningful metric here?

I can't just use $\sqrt{CI_a^2 + CI_b^2}$, right? At least not without some assumption. Or can I?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18215. Do you know whether the CIs are independent?  Do you have any sense of what the underlying sampling distribution of $a-b$ might look like?

Comment: Good questions. They are based on validation data and then prediction at the validation data location. I am not sure whether that makes them dependent.  They are based on binning along a certain dimension and those bins are decided by the empirical density. They are uniform in the other directions

Comment: "Prediction at the validation data location" does not describe a confidence interval.  Could you therefore be more specific about how these intervals are constructed and from what data?

Comment: @whuber, I have a surrogate function $f(\vec{x})$, trained on ${\vec{x},f}$ and I have validation data ${\vec{x'},f'}$. For all intents and purposes, I am looking at $E(f(\vec{x'})) - E(f')$ where I also have the CI's computed from a regular bootstrap estimate on $E(\cdot)$. Does that help?

Comment: I don't understand that because I can think of many possible interpretations.  For instance, is $x^\prime$ random or not?  How about the "surrogate function"?  Exactly what parameters do these "CIs" apply to?  It helps (immensely) to describe a concrete example, preferably a version of the actual problem you face.