# Subtracting Limits of Two Confidence Intervals to generate the Confidence Interval for the Difference Between Two Means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, inference

I wanted to know why it isn't statistically correct or correct in a probabilistic sense to subtract the lower confidence limits and upper confidence limits of the separate confidence intervals of two population means to generate the confidence interval of the difference between the two means (or for e.g Difference between Two Population Proportions etc... ).

Comment: Essentially because the standard error of the difference is not the difference of the standard errors.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18259/919 for a discussion of what subtracting the confidence limits actually does.