# What would be the right statistical test here?

Tags: confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, z-test

I want to know whether the proportions for two samples are the same.

0-hypothesis: The proportions are the same for both samples
Alternative hypothesis: The proportions are different.

I know the sample sizes (200 and 1800) and the proportions (45 % and 40 %).

The problem is that I arrive at different conclusions when I do different kinds of tests.

When calculating confidence intervals (95 %), I arrive at the conclusion that the CI's are overlapping, meaning that I can't reject the 0 hypothesis.

SampleSize1 = 200
SampleSize2 = 1800
SampleOccurrences1 = 90
SampleOccurrences2 = 680
SampleProportion1 = 45 %
SampleProportion2 = 38 %

I calculate the confidence interval for each of the samples using Excel:

z = 1.96
StdError = SQRT(SampleProportionX*(1-SampleProportionX)/SampleSizeX)
MarginOfError =  z * StdError
Confidence interval = SampleProportionX +/- MarginOfError

As the confidence intervals are overlapping, I can't reject the 0-hypothesis.

When calculating the Z-value, I arrive at the conclusion that the 0-hypothesis should be rejected.

I calculate the Z-value as follows:

p1 = SampleProportion1
p2 = SampleProportion2
p = (SampleOccurrences1 + SampleOccurrences2) / (SampleSize1 + SampleSize2)

Z = (SampleProportion1 - SampleProportion2) / SQRT(p*(1-p)*(1 / SampleSize1 + 1 / SampleSize2))

As Z > 1.96, I reject the 0-hypothesis.

Why do I get different results, and which test is the correct to use?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You'll need to explain in a little more detail how you're performing the tests & calculating the confidence intervals.

Comment: Testing for overlapping confidence intervals can be done but does not yield the level of confidence you might think.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18259/919.