# Conservative confidence interval for linear combination of parameters

Tags: confidence-interval

Consider two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and let $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ denote the joint $95\%$ confidence region of $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Take the parameter $\delta\equiv f(\alpha,\beta)$ where $f$ is a linear function of $(\alpha,\beta)$. For example, $\delta=\alpha+\beta$.

Let $C_{\delta}$ denote the joint $95\%$ confidence region of $\delta$.

Consider the interval $$T\equiv \{c\in \mathbb{R}: \exists (a,b) \in C_{\alpha,\beta} \text{ s.t. } c=f(a,b)\}$$

**Question:** is $T \supseteq C_{\delta}$?

Comment: No.  But with care, something can be said.  This is essentially the same question addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18215.  Apply that one to the parameters $(\alpha, -\beta).$ I understand implicitly you assume confidence intervals are independent, for otherwise the answer *a fortiori* is no due to the dependence.

Comment: Thanks. What if instead I consider the proper joint confidence region of $(\alpha,\beta)$ (call it $C$) and I compute $T\equiv \{c\in \mathbb{R}: \exists (a,b) \in C \text{ s.t. } c=a+b\}$?

Comment: By reparameterizing your question (use, say, parameters $(\alpha,\alpha+\beta)$) it simplifies to this: is the projection of a 95% confidence region $C$ onto one of the parameters a 95% confidence interval?  In this form it is easy to check, by computing any simple example, that this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks. However, I believe that the projection of the $95\%$ confidence region onto one of the parameters should contain the $95\%$ confidence interval. This is what I mean by "conservative". For example, if I look at the classical t-test versus F-test picture for OLS, the projection of the ellipse contains the individual intervals.

Comment: +1 That's a good question.