# How to interpret interact_plot for categorical x continuous interactions

Tags: r, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, interaction, lm

I'm wondering how to interpret `interact_plot` plots for categorical x continuous interactions. Here's a toy example to illustrate:

```
df <- data.frame(mtcars)
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * wt + am, data = df)
summary(fit)
```

Which gives these coefficient values:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  41.4641     4.5358   9.141  1.9e-09 ***
cyl6         -8.6617    10.3634  -0.836 0.411185    
cyl8        -16.8621     5.2733  -3.198 0.003738 ** 
wt           -6.1883     1.6499  -3.751 0.000937 ***
am           -0.9015     1.5145  -0.595 0.557030    
cyl6:wt       2.1227     3.3954   0.625 0.537522    
cyl8:wt       3.8446     1.7733   2.168 0.039880 *
```

And here's the `interact_plot`:

```
library(interactions)
interact_plot(fit, pred = wt, modx = cyl)
```

[image: interact_plot]

Looking at this plot alongside the `summary()` output above, we can see the following:

```
# Effect on mpg of moving from 4 to 6 cylinders at 1000 lbs (i.e., wt = 1):
-8.6617 + 2.1227 = -6.539
# Effect on mpg of moving from 4 to 6 cylinders at 5000 lbs (i.e., wt = 5):
-8.6617 + 2.1227 * 5 = 1.9518

# Effect on mpg of moving from 4 to 8 cylinders at 1000 lbs:
-16.8621 + 3.8446 = -13.0175
# Effect on mpg of moving from 4 to 8 cylinders at 5000 lbs:
-16.8621 + 3.8446 * 5 = 2.3609
```

The non-trivial estimate values for `cyl6:wt` and `cyl8:wt` suggest that there is heterogeneity in the effect of `cyl` on `mpg`, such that the effect of moving from 4 to 6 cylinders or 4 to 8 cylinders varies depending on the weight of the vehicle. This can be seen from the difference in slope between the `cyl = 4` line and the `cyl = 6` and `cyl = 8` lines, respectively. Moreover, the interaction between moving from 4 to 8 cylinders and weight in particular is significant.

Here are my two questions:

#### 1. How do I interpret `interact_plot`s more generally?

Is the following correct for how to interpret these types of plots generally?

- **Parallel lines** indicate an absence of heterogeneity/interaction.
- **Differently sloped lines** indicate heterogeneity. As in the example above, the difference in effect on `mpg` from different level of `cyl` varies for different values of `wt`.
- **Lines that cross over** indicate a particular type of heterogeneity whereby the difference in effect "flips" for some values. For example, if you want to reduce mpg, you'd want to go for 6 or 8 cylinder cars if it weighs less than about 4000 lbs, and a 4 cylinder car above that.

Is that correct?

#### 2. How do I interpret confidence bands in `interact_plot`s?

Consider the same plot from above, but this time with confidence intervals:

```
library(interactions)
interact_plot(fit, pred = wt, modx = cyl, interval = TRUE)
```

[image: interact_plot with confidence intervals]

The documentation makes clear that `interval = TRUE` gives 95% confidence intervals by default. What I'm not clear on is how to interpret these in the context of the p-values I get from `summary()` above.

At first I thought that, since there are points (for low `wt` values) where the green ribbon (`cyl = 8`) and the blue ribbon do not touch, we can conclude that the corresponding interaction term (`cyl8:wt`) is significantly different from 0, as per the `summary()` output above.

But that can't be right, as shown by this example:

```
df$vs <- as.factor(df$vs)
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ vs * wt + am + cyl, data = df)
summary(fit2)
```

Which gives these coefficient values:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  30.6802     3.5817   8.566 6.61e-09 ***
vs1          10.1609     4.6323   2.193   0.0378 *  
wt           -2.4202     0.9262  -2.613   0.0150 *  
am           -0.7796     1.5644  -0.498   0.6226    
cyl6         -2.2400     1.6988  -1.319   0.1993    
cyl8         -5.7899     2.5499  -2.271   0.0320 *  
vs1:wt       -3.4214     1.6386  -2.088   0.0471 *
```

And the following `interact_plot`:

```
library(interactions)
interact_plot(fit2, pred = wt, modx = vs, interval = TRUE)
```

[image]

Here we have a significant interaction term (`vs1:wt`) but no point at which the two ribbons do not overlap.

So how are these confidence bands to be interpreted?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How do I interpret `interact_plots` more generally?*

Parallel lines, as you state, mean that the association of outcome with the continuous predictor does not change as a function of the level of the categorical predictor.

If the slopes are different, that association does depend on the level of the categorical predictor. Inevitably, at some point lines with different slopes in two dimensions will cross. The question is whether the crossing point represents any realistic situation. For example, you suggest:

> ... if you want to reduce mpg, you'd want to go for 6 or 8 cylinder cars if it weighs less than about 4000 lbs, and a 4 cylinder car above that.

But look at the actual distribution of cylinder numbers by car weight (weight is in thousands of pounds in the data frame):

```
with(df, ftable(lowWt = wt < 4,cylinders = cyl))
##       cylinders  4  6  8
## lowWt                   
## FALSE            0  0  4
## TRUE            11  7 10
```

There aren't any 4-cylinder cars with weights over 4000 pounds. The ease of producing interaction plots like these can lead you astray from real-world conditions.

*How do I interpret confidence bands in `interact_plots`?*

The confidence bands are for the individual lines. Overlap between 95% confidence bands does not rule out statistical significance of the difference between two situations. See the explanation for t-test confidence intervals in this [answer by @whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18259/28500):

> **To summarize,** the failure of two $2\alpha$-size confidence intervals of means to overlap is significant evidence of a difference in means at a level equal to $2e \alpha^{1.91}$, provided the two samples have approximately equal standard deviations and are approximately the same size.

On that basis, failure of 95% confidence intervals (based on $2\alpha = 0.05$) to overlap means $p < 0.005$ for the difference, approximately. As a guide for illustrating a difference between two conditions at $p < 0.05$, I suppose you could use something like 83% confidence intervals.

With interactions, however, it's much better to illustrate specific comparisons between realistic situations. For example, based on this data set *don't* do comparisons involving 4-cylinder cars with weights over 3190 pounds, as there aren't any.