# If I have two confidence intervals that overlap, what can I say about the two statistics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Suppose I had two statistics and I were to construct confidence intervals off the two statistics, and that they overlap. From what I understand, we cannot make a statement about the difference between the two statistics in terms of significance.

Would this statement rely on the underlying distributions of the two statistics being the same? Can I compare confidence intervals with different sample sizes, sampling collection, etc?

Comment: You cannot compare these, you have to compute their difference and compute the CI of the difference.

Comment: @user2974951 Not so fast.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18259/919 partially answers this question by showing a way of comparing two Student t confidence intervals of the mean.