# What measures of difference can be used to compare two confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval

Suppose I have two confidence intervals that measure accuracy of two different classifiers on the same data. In the first, I have $0.9087 \pm 0.0073$ for one, and $0.9123 \pm 0.0075$ for the other. These intervals overlap by more than their margin of error.

Is there a nice measure or graphical representation that can elaborate on how these are different without resorting to barplots? For example, is it fair to compute the percentage of overlap between these two intervals?

Comment: Probably comparing two means with uncertainties is a better term for this. A recent paper [Comparing uncertainties—Are they really different?](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00769-022-01501-2), suggests F-test.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking, but perhaps you might find the ideas at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18259/919 to be relevant.